Differences in composite components behaviour when switching from JSF 2.2 to Jakarta Faces 4.0
Trying to switch a JSF 2.2 application to Jakarta Faces 4.0.
The application uses some composite components to apply common styles and layout around different faces components. There are composite components also for labes and error messages, which basically use h:outputLabel and h:message respectivly.
The problem now is - at least when such components are created within ui:repeat, that error messages are no longer displayed and on the label for-attribute there is a missmatch with the id of the input field - which I guess is also the reason for the error-message to not being displayed because of the mismatch in the for-attribute.
So a simple example would look like
<ui:repeat id="loop"...>
<cc:label cFor="myInput" />
<cc:input cId="myInput" />
<cc:error cFor="myInput />
</ui:repeat>

cFor and cId are then set within the components implementation with
 <h:outputLabel for="#{cc.attrs.cFor}" /> 

and
 <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.cId}" /> 

While this worked in JSF2 it is no longer working in Jakarta Faces 4.0 because something with the composite components id (as it is a naming container) seems to have changed.
Resulting HTML in JSF 2.2 was something like:
<label for="loop:1:j_idt182:myInput />
<inputText id="loop:1:j_idt182:myInput />
....

So the dynamic id j_idt182 matched.
Now in Jakarta Faces 4.0 the result looks like
<label for="loop:1:j_idt192:myInput />
<input id="loop:1:j_idt195:myInput />

So it seems that the ids of the surrounding naming container is part of the for attribute - at least when they are surrounded by other naming containers.  Is this intended?
How would I (in the given situation with surrounding naming container) ever be able to connect the label (or error message) to the input field (in another naming container) without programmatically retrieving the real client id via additional bean?
Adding an explicit id to the input field component would thus also never work?
<cc:label for="myInput:myInput" />
<cc:input id="myInput" cId="myInput" />

